# Is Thread Scheduler is part of JVM or Part of OS?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, scheduler

So I want to understand how thread scheduler in java chooses a particular thread. Since it is not taking priority into account. I want to know the actual working of it. Share some resources

Comment: It could be either or both; the Java spec is intentionally silent on the question. In particular, there are JVMs that run without any underlying OS.

Comment: According to my research, there is no term as JVM thread Scheduler JVM will create a thread for the OS and OS does the Scheduling

Answer (score 0):

Java spec does not say anything on it.

In general, JVM would simply use the underlying threading mechanism provided by the OS, which would imply POSIX Threads (pthreads) on UNIX (Mac OS X, Linux, etc.) and would imply WIN32 threads on Windows. Typically, those systems use a round-robin strategy by default.

so JVM uses operating system native threads, and the OS does the scheduling, not the JVM.

[Check here for Java thread priority?](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml)

[How JVM thread scheduler control threads for multiprocessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759261/how-jvm-thread-scheduler-control-threads-for-multiprocessors)

Comment: The second link which you have mentioned clearly helped me out. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @sandeepnegi1996 in that case, can you accept the answer.